# In a Voltage Regulator, what is it that decides the maximum resistance of the resistor and why?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I need to find the maximum resistance that R can have. This is what I know:
10V<=Vin<=15V
Iz>=0.2mA
0A<=IL<=1A
Vz=5.7 V.
hFE=50

I have derived the equation \$R=\frac{Vin-Vz}{I_z+\frac{I_L}{1+hFE}}\$

But how do I know which value is the biggest R can have and why is that?
I read on Wikipedia that 
\$R_{max}=\frac{Vmin-Vz}{I_Zmin+\frac{I_Lmax}{1+hFE}}\$
but I just don't understand why.

[image: circuit]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$R_{max}=\frac{Vmin-Vz}{I_Zmin+\frac{I_Lmax}{1+hFE}}\$

What this tells you is this: -

- Vin(min) must be greater than Vz or you start to eat away at the zener regulation voltage and it starts to droop too much below the nominal zener voltage
- For a zener voltage to be "in spec" you need a certain current flowing thru it hence Iz(min) (as a minimum) needs to flow thru the resistor
- The current thru the base needs to be taken into account because if you don't the zener voltage will drop

From what you say Vin(min) is 10V and Vz is 5.7 volts - that's good - there's a few volts across the collector base resistor. Now, you say the load current is 1A and, I estimate with rules of thumb and experience that the hFE of the transistor might be in the order of 30 for this type of scenario. this means the base current might be 33mA. You say hFE is 50 but, without examining the data sheet I have my doubts so, I choose to opt for a hFE of 30.

The current needed by the zener diode might be 5mA to sustain a Vz of 5.7 volts hence, the current needed thru the collector-base resistor is 38mA(min).

Given that the volt drop is Vin(min) - Vz = 4.3 volts and the current is 38mA, the value of R = 113 ohms.

That's the way I would calculate Rmin.

Answer (score 0):

If R is too large, there will not be enough current flowing through it to ensure that the zener diode is reverse biased with the correct voltage across it.

The current through R divides into two components - Zener current Iz(nominal) and base current. Ideally base current can be neglected. And you will choose R such that the Zener gets a little more than the nominal current (10-20% more should be fine).

So R < (vin - vz) / (Iznom * 1.10)

Comment: Okay that makes sense, we want to find the value of R that makes it possible to maintain 5V over Vout for 10V<Vin<15V. But I don't understand why it for instance should be I_Lmax?

Comment: ILmax is the largest load current. At that point your transistor will need the largest base current, which comes from your resistor.

Comment: Oh okay, so we are looking at the case when V_in is at a minimum, because that gives us the value of R that makes it possible to let enough current through to base to have ILmax for all different values of Vin?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

The resistor value is completely dependant on the transistor that you select. This resistor acts merely as a pull up resistor. What happens is that the presence of the resistor makes sure that the transistor stays on all the time. Without this pull up the transistor will stay off and the whole operation fails.

Now, as to your question of the equation, the whole magic is in the hfe(dc gain) of the transistor. Most of the transistors have gains in the order of a few 10s to a few 100s. The gain is the factor by which the transistor amplifies the current.

In the equation you derived all the parameters are more or less fixed except hfe and Il(load current). So, the amplification you desire governs the selection of your R. 
In other words, if you need 1amp of load current,hfe would be "x" and hence the resistance is something. But if you need 2amps of current, the hfe would be "y" and so on and so forth.

Hence-forth, select the resistor based on these 2 factors

Comment: You also require enough extra current through the resistor to keep enough current passing through the Zener diode to keep it at its nominal voltage.

Comment: I don't believe in magic especially when it comes to transistors or even jesus.